# Conditional probability after drawing the first card of any color

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games

My card deck has $2n$ cards, $n$ black and $n$ red. I keep drawing cards (without replacing) until I reach the first black card. What is the probability that the next card is again black?

Surprisingly (to me) it seems that for each $n>1$ the answer is $1/2$, at least it is for $n=2,3,4$.

Is there a way of seeing this without going through all the options?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4654695/in-a-deck-of-cards-do-a-queen-and-a-non-queen-have-equal-chances-of-being-the-c/4654759#4654759).  The argument given there shows that each card is equally likely to be the one following the first black (at least if $n>1$) and that's all you need.

Comment: Great, thanks! I did some searching before but somehow missed that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4654695/in-a-deck-of-cards-do-a-queen-and-a-non-queen-have-equal-chances-of-being-the-c/4654759#4654759) is essentially a duplicate, but the claim is so unintuitive (and, I think, unfamiliar) that it may be worth repeating the argument in this context.

Indeed, suppose the cards are numbered $\{b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$ and $\{r_1, \cdots, r_n\}$.  Pick any card $X$ and remove it from the deck.  Now shuffle the $X-$less deck.  There are $(2n-1)!$ ways to do that.  Having done so, insert $X$ into the deck behind the first black card (note:  this is where we require that $n>1$).  In this way, we see that there are $(2n-1)!$ shuffles of the full deck in which $X$ is the card following the first black card.  Thus the probability that $X$ is the card following the first black card is $$\frac {(2n-1)!}{(2n)!}=\frac 1{2n}$$ so we see that each card is equally likely to be the card following the first black.

The desired claim follows at once.